# HBase completebulkload returns exception

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, guava

I am trying to bulk-populate an HBase table quickly from a text file (several GB) by using the bulk loading method [described](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#arch.bulk.load) in the Hadoop docs.

I have created an HFile which I now want to push to my HBase table.

When I use this command:

```
hadoop jar /home/hxcaine/hadoop/lib/hbase.jar completebulkload /user/hxcaine/dbpopulate/output/cf1 my_hbase_table
```

The job starts and then I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/ThreadFactoryBuilder
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.doBulkLoad(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.run(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:696)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles.main(LoadIncrementalHFiles.java:701)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Driver.main(Driver.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        ... 17 more
```

However, I can see that the Guava jar is in my classpath and when I check inside the jar I can see `ThreadFactoryBuilder.class`.

I am using these versions (and stuck with them):

- Hadoop 0.20.2-cdh3u3
- HBase 0.90.4-cdh3u3
- Guava jar: /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20/lib/guava-r09-jarjar.jar

I do have an older Guava jar in my classpath but I don't know where it came from, I don't suppose it should have an effect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what happens if you run:

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=`hbase classpath`
```

before running the load? From the stack trace, it looks like the jar is needed by one of the actual tasks though I am surprised to see that this actually kicks off an M/R job.

Comment: You are a life-saver. No way I'd have found that otherwise, thank you!