# Hadoop with Hbase: Guava jar exists in classpath, but execution throws class not found exception for "ThreadFactoryBuilder" class

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, hbase, guava

*Facts:*

1) I am running Hadoop 1.0.3 with Hbase 0.92.1 on a distributed setup, and I am trying to bulk import data through code.

2) I add all required jars (including the guava-r09.jar) to my hadoop classpath by this way:

HADOOP_CLASSPATH=mia-0.7-job.jar:/usr/local/hbase0921/lib/guava-r09.jar:Jama-1.0‌​.2.jar /usr/local/hadoop103/bin/hadoop jar myJar.jar mainPackage/MyMain -libjars mia-0.7-job.jar,/usr/local/hbe0921/lib/guava-r09.jar,Jama-1.0.2.jar

*Problem:*

Despite the fact that ThreadFactoryBuilder.class exists in guava-r09.jar, I encounter the following: ClassNotFoundException:com.google.common.util.concurrent.ThreadFactoryBuilder

I would be grateful if anyone could shed a light on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you mean by "copying its folder"? In case you have a jar file, you need to add it explicitly as jar (there's nothing like directory of jars in the CLASSPATH). In case you have a directory tree containing class files, I must ask "WHY"? And in such a case you should check if from your "eclipse class directory" you really get via "com/google/common/collect" to "Multimap.class".

Comment: @maaartinus Besides the edited question, I would like to mention that I am aware of this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11692497/hbase-completebulkload-returns-exception , 

which does not solve the problem in my case. Any ideas? Thank you again for your interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the guava jar to job's distributed cache via:

DistributedCache.addFileToClassPath(pathToGuavaAtHDFS, yourConfiguration);